# Which Plugins are available for customizing keycloak registration

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-nodejs-connect

We are working on an Open Source (AGPL) Chrome extension: [Digital Assistant Client](https://github.com/Digital-Assistant/Digital_Assistant_Client)

I want to utilize the keycloak functionality for registering the user but i have few requirements where the user email address to be verified and want to validate the users domain too. Is there any available plugins which can be used for Integrating with existing keycloak functionality. Also i am using keycloak version 23.0.0 and there is no provision for adding attributes into the keycloak.

Can any guide me for any existing plugins available. Thanks for yourr response

Answer (score 0):

The email verification is a built in feature in Keycloak

[image: Force email validation]

The mail domain validation is not available out of the box but can be easily done via an additional extension (checkout keycloak-mail-whitelisting as an example)

Finally, additional attributes can be added to the registration form view the "User Profile" feature which became official in 24.0 (could be enable for previous versions).

Checkout https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#user-profile

Kindly from [Cloud-IAM](https://www.cloud-iam.com)